# How do I label the rows and columns in a diagonal matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I'm creating a diagonal matrix of variances in R, thus:

```
D <- diag(data $ Variances, 
          length(data $ Variances), 
          length(data $ Variances))
```

Does anyone know how to add row and column labels?  The labels are species names in the column "Species" from dataframe "data", where the column "Variances" was also taken from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `colnames(D) <- your.col.names` and `rownames(D) <- your.row.names` to add column and row names to your matrix D.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Sorry that was such a simple question!

Answer (score 4):

`dimnames` is another useful function, see `?dimnanes` for further details.

```
> Mat <- matrix(1:12, ncol=3) # creating a matrix
> Mat  # no dimnames
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    9
[2,]    2    6   10
[3,]    3    7   11
[4,]    4    8   12
> dimnames(Mat) <- list(letters[1:4], LETTERS[1:3])
> Mat # with dimnames
  A B  C
a 1 5  9
b 2 6 10
c 3 7 11
d 4 8 12
```